# What is vendor_id in CloudJobTicket (CJT)?

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

How is this vendor Id gonna use when creating a cloudJobTicket & sending the print job to cloud? what can it do?

link -> https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#cjt

Answer (score 1):

1. **vendor_id**

`vendor_id` is an attribute that appears in some **CDD** as well as **CJT** items (color, media size, dpi, etc). Generally, it holds an internal ID that the printer uses to disambiguate same values that need to have different behaviour on the printer.

For example, a printer may support 1 resolution (300dpi) but 3 quality settings (draft, normal, best). Since there's no quality setting either on **CDD** or **CJT**, their **CDD** could look like:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "print": {
        "dpi": {
            "option": [
                {
                    "horizontal_dpi": 300,
                    "vertical_dpi": 300,
                    "vendor_id": "draft300dpi"
                    "custom_display_name": "300dpi - DRAFT"
                },
                {
                    "horizontal_dpi": 300,
                    "vertical_dpi": 300,
                    "is_default": true,
                    "vendor_id": "normal300dpi"
                    "custom_display_name": "300dpi - NORMAL"
                },
                {
                    "horizontal_dpi": 300,
                    "vertical_dpi": 300,
                    "vendor_id": "best300dpi"
                    "custom_display_name": "300dpi - BEST"
                }
            ]
        },
        (...)
    }
}
```

If in you set the first option for the **CJT**, it will look like:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "print": {
        "dpi": {
            "horizontal_dpi": 300,
            "vertical_dpi": 300,
            "vendor_id": "normal300dpi"
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't set up `vendor_id` in your **CJT**, printer will not be able to disambiguate between its internal options, and may not decide what you really selected.

`vendor_id` is always optional for a printer to provide it in the **CDD**. As a consequence, it is also optional for a client to provide it in the **CJT** (check in the documentation, it is always preceded by the `optional` keyword). My recommendation is that you forward the same value the printer is providing to you for the setting you select in your **CJT**, in case it provides something.

2. **VendorTicketItem**

On the other hand, then there is the `VendorTicketItem`, which can be used by a printer to expose additional capabilities that are not covered by the items that the specification provides. Printers can use it to advertise these additional features in their CDD, and clients can set them in the **CJT**.